# Android Log adds package name at the beginning of a log message

Tags: android, logging

in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070171/android-bluetooth-finds-devices-with-empty-names-on-lg-phone) question I posted you can see the originating code sample for this log, and the reason it is generated:

```
08-15 22:54:16.500: INFO/SOD:BT_Receiver(16151): <!>com.nu.art.software.log.Log 69<!> Bluetooth device found: [bbbb:Demo gizmo 2], 5a0204, 6C:0E:0D:77:B0:96
08-15 22:54:16.578: INFO/SOD:BT_Receiver(16151): <!>com.nu.art.software.log.Log 69<!> Bluetooth device found: [aaaa:Demo gizmo 1], 5a020c, 00:26:CC:81:AF:AD
08-15 22:54:33.820: INFO/SOD:BT_Receiver(16151): <!>com.nu.art.software.log.Log 69<!> Bluetooth device found: Zomaar Iemand, 5a0204, 20:21:A5:C0:CF:6F
```

My question is where does the text, "`<!>com.nu.art.software.log.Log 69<!>`" is coming from?

I don't add it myself, any where. I have a wrapper over the Android original Log, and without a doubt the Message is been tunneled to the Native log as it is composed in the snipped, and the native Log append the package as a prefix to the message, why is that?

I'm running the project working on android 2.1, and LG phone.

Thanks,

Adam.

Comment: IIRC in a comment to a deleted answer you said the program does not log with the extra text on other devices.  But do other programs log with the extra text on this device?

Comment: Some do, some don't, for example, if I run other application on the device I don't see that the log has the package attached to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is where does the text, "com.nu.art.software.log.Log
>   69" is coming from?

This is added to the logcat output text by LG's Android (in my experience).

Answer (score 0):

```
Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth device found: " + device.getName() + ", " + device.getBluetoothClass() + ", " + device.getAddress());
```

Your code uses a log "TAG" which you have not shown in your posted excerpt.

The "extraneous" text is appearing right before the text following the TAG in your logging invocation, so it's at least a suspicious candidate.

Comment: The Log wrapper adds the application name(SOD) before the TAG(BT_Receiver), and separates them with ':'